# UpdateView and CreateView - Is the code efficient or could improved on?

Tags: python, django

For Django 1.6, This is my final code that works. The logic is, if a database object doesn't exist for the user then go to 'account_add' to add the account. I didn't want to use a user_profile or modify the user object directly for specific issues, so please do not suggest those. What I would like to know is if this code is written well, or could be written better and more efficient?

```
class AccountCreateOrModify():
    model = Employee
    form_class = AccountForm
    template_name = 'bot_data/account_modify.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')


class ViewEmployee(LoginRequiredMixin, 
        DetailView):

    model = Employee
    template_name = 'bot_data/employee_detail.html'

    def dispatch(self, request,
            *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            pk = self.request.user.pk
            queryset = self.model.objects.get(user_assigned=pk)
            return super(ViewEmployee, 
                    self).dispatch(request, 
                            *args, **kwargs)
        except Employee.DoesNotExist:
            return redirect('account_add')

    def get_object(self):
            user = self.request.user.id
            find_user = self.model.objects.get(id=user)
            return find_user

class AccountModify(LoginRequiredMixin, 
        AccountCreateOrModify,
        UpdateView):

    def dispatch(self, request,
            *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            pk = self.request.user.pk
            queryset = self.model.objects.get(user_assigned=pk)
            return super(AccountModify, 
                    self).dispatch(request, 
                            *args, **kwargs)
        except Employee.DoesNotExist:
            return redirect('account_add')

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        pk = self.request.user.pk
        queryset = self.model.objects.get(user_assigned=pk)
        return queryset





class AccountCreateRecord(LoginRequiredMixin,
        AccountCreateOrModify,
        CreateView):
    print "filler"
```

Comment: Questions regarding performance, code integrity, best practices, etc. should be posted at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: That aside, does `Employee` extend `User`? Are there any FK relationships? I'm just wondering if this could all be simplified with Django's `get_or_create` method.

Comment: this might be better suited for code review.  WHat happens if a user is not logged in? ie no `request.user.pk` or `self.request.user.id`? If login is required django provides decorators to require login

Comment: `LoginRequiredMixin` will force the user to use their ldap account log in. `user_assigned = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='racker_assigned')` for `class Employee(models.Model):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try blocks should contains a single line:

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    pk = self.request.user.pk
    try:
        queryset = self.model.objects.get(user_assigned=pk)
    except Employee.DoesNotExist:
        return redirect('account_add')
    return super(ViewEmployee, self).dispatch(
        request, *args, **kwargs)
```

If except wasn't returning anything, look for `try`, `except`, `else` block succession.

classes should inherits from object or have no parenthesis:

```
class AccountCreateOrModify(object): # a bit better
    pass

class AccountCreateOrModify: # avoid useless parenthesis
    pass
```

If Employee is an abstract class you can avoid to hit database.

```
def get_object(self):
    user = self.request.user.id
    find_user = self.model.objects.get(id=user)
    return find_user
```

Why "print" in your last class, did you know about the pass (no-op) keyword?

```
class AccountCreateRecord(LoginRequiredMixin, AccountCreateOrModify,
                          CreateView):
    pass
```